# Trying to subset a dataset to only include data from a list of 61 specific dates

Tags: r

I am having issue with extracting all rows that correspond to the last day of the month from a large dataset.

The data has 34 variables but the key ones involved are :

```
$ pageId                     : Factor w/ x levels
$ clientId                   : Factor w/ x levels
$ pageTitle                  : Factor w/ x levels 
$ Date                       : POSIXlt, format: "2012-12-31" "2013-01-01" 
$ Yr                         : Factor w/ 8 levels "2009","2010",..
$ Mn                         : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4"...
```

I want to subset my data such that I only have all the rows for the final days of each month. applied across all clients/pageids/pagetitles.

I've been capable of generating a list of the last days of the month using the following function:

```
lastDayMonth=function(x)
{           
  x=as.Date(as.character(x))
day = format(x,format="%d")
monthYr = format(x,format="%Y-%m")
y = tapply(day,monthYr, max)
last=as.Date(paste(row.names(y),y,sep="-"))
as.Date(strptime(last, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

A similar problem was attempted before but only trying to extract out 2 specific dates:

```
sub.4 <- subset(df, POSIXtime >= as.POSIXct('2013-08-05 06:00') &
                POSIXtime <= as.POSIXct('2013-08-05 13:45'))
```

I want to extract out 61 rows per each client id whilst retaining all other columns.

Does anyone have a neat solution for this which won't require me to expand out the above solution for 61 dates?

All help greatly appreciated. If you need any additional information or if anything is unclear then please let me know. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice trick posted by Dirk Eddelbuettel somewhere on this site:

You get a sequence of the first days of the month and then subtract 1, obtaining the last days of the month.

```
lastDayofMonth <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="month")-1
```

Then just subset using `%in%`:

```
newDf <- df[df$date %in% lastDayofMonth,]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `as.yearqtr` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
subset(df, date %in% as.Date(as.yearqtr(date, "%b%Y"), frac = 1))
```